# Method while loop C#

Tags: c#, methods, while-loop

So im learning c# I'm about 2 weeks into this adventure. I'm trying to get a better understanding of what methods are what they can be used for and what there purpose is.

This is what I came up with. But it is not working as i expected.

```
 public void testmethod(int lower ,int upper , int num)
{
    while (lower < upper)
    {
        ++num;
        MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
    }
```

Than I have a button that shows a message box

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testmethod(1 , 4 , 1);
    }
```

From my limited knowledge of c# I think this should show a message box till it reaches the number 4. Im passing on the parameters for upper and lower in the method. Is this correct? It keeps going it never stops.

Comment: while ( 1 < 4 ) will always be true

Comment: You don't actually change the value of either `upper` or `lower` so you'll never hit a halting condition

Comment: Because `lower < upper` never turns to false. You need `num < upper`

Comment: I think there is a logic problem, not a loop problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is : `while (lower < upper)`

However, *you never modify* `lower` or `upper`. Just `num`. Thus, your condition always remains true, and its an infinite loop.

You need to check somehow against `num` (how is hard to say, since you are passing it in), or modify `lower` (which may make more sense).

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that you're incrementing `num` rather than `lower`.  It will keep getting larger, but the test `lower < upper` will never return false because neither is changing.  You need to either increment `lower` itself or change your while condition like this:

```
while (num < upper) {
    ++num;
    MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
}
```

Incidentally, it's rather odd to pass a counter variable like `num` into the method.  You could just initialize it to 1 (or `0`) within `testmethod`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new but learning. I wanted to test my theories on what I thought methods were, and actually got a better understanding of what a while loop does. I seen what you were saying when I did a break point and look at the local values. ( I did this before I posted but i just wasnt seeing it. This was a very valuable test for me. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will print 2 3 4.  Because you never assigned a new value to lower

```
  while (lower < upper)
            {
                ++num;
                Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
                lower = num; //Added.  Else the loop is infinite
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a infinity loop, cuz your condition is always return "true".

You can do something like:

```
    public void testmethod(int lower ,int upper , int num)
    {
       while ((lower = num) < upper)
       {
          ++num;
          MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
       }
    }
```

Also check this out => http://www.dotnetperls.com/while

Answer (score 0):

```
while (lower < upper)
```

This is an inifity loop or never be executed, because you do not change `lower` or `upper` in the loop.

You have to increase `lower` or decrease `upper`

Or just use a foreach loop:

```
for(int i = lower; i <= upper; i++)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never changing `lower` or `upper`, so it never finishes the loop. The loop only goes while the condition is still true. You're probably looking for something like this in your `testmethod`:

```
while (num < upper)
{
  MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
  num++;
}
```

This will show the value for `num` and then increment. Previously you were incrementing it (hence the `++` before the variable), and only then printing it.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
while (lower < upper)
```

- Checks if `lower` is less than `upper`. (1 is less than 4, therefore true)
- So it does the loop.
- Then it checks the condition again. (1 is ***still*** less than 4, therefore true)

So... when and why do you think the loop will ever end?
It only ends if one of the variables, `lower` or `upper`, changes.

But the only variable you change is `num`, which is ***not*** used in the test!

Answer (score 0):

It keeps running as long as `lower` is less than `upper`. Since you are not changing the value of `lower` or `upper` inside of your loop it never ends. You need to increase `lower` by one in each iteration:

```
while (lower < upper)
{
    ++num;
    MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
    ++lower;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because while loop condition is always true.

Try lower++ instead of ++num